# Non-continuous Distribution Function

Tags: probability

Given

$$F(X) = \begin{cases}
0 \text{ for }x < -1\\
\frac{x+5}{10} \text{ for } -1 \leq x < 3\\
1 \text{ for }x \geq 3
\end{cases}$$ which is a discrete and continuous distribution function,

I must find $P(-1 \leq x < 2)$.

Apparently, this is equal to $\frac{7}{10}$, but I do not understand why. I know that $P(-1\leq x <2)= F(2) - F(-1)$, but then I calculuate $\frac{3}{10}$. Can anyone explain?

[image]

Comment: Should your $P(1\le x<2)$ in the last line of your question be $P(-1\le x <2)$?, and $F(2)-F(1)$ should be $F(2)-F(-1)$?

Answer (score 1):

I would think of it this way - in your example these two probabilities are equivalent:

$$P(-1 \leq x < 2) =P(x<2)$$

That is, each one implies the other. So then we have

$$P(x<2) = {7 \over 10}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Being a mixed distribution, you have to be careful at single points with positive probability.  So this distribution has a point probability of $.4$ at $x=-1$.  This is included in $P(-1\le X<2)$.   This is what is causing the discrepancy of $.4$ between your answer and the 'official' answer.

Comment: Do you mean this distribution has a point probability of $.4$ at $x= -1$?

Comment: Yes, right.  Sorry.  I will edit in a correction.

Comment: So this is my diagram for this distribution function: http://i.imgur.com/ROX5YHE.jpg Even though I think I drew this correctly, I do not understand why we are being messed up.

Comment: In order to include the probability at $-1$, really we need to say that $P(-1\le X<2)=F(2)-\lim_{x\to -1^-}F(x)=.7-0$.  (If you just subtract off $F(-1)$ you lose the probability ($.4$) concentrated at $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Emm

$$
P( -1 \le x <2) = F(2) - F (-1) + P (x = -1) - P (x = 2) = 0.7 - 0.4 + 0.4 - 0 = 0.7
$$

Since you have a jump at $-1$